# Defining type of parameter for the directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsdoc, ngdoc

How to define the types of parameters for the directive in angularjs?
What type to use for `&` binding?

See ngdoc or jsdoc in example code.

UPD:
My goal is to get answers on below questions

```
 * @param {<< what to write here? >>} parentContextExpression
 * @param {<< what to write here? >>} oneWayParameter
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('exampleDir', exampleDir);

/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @module app
 * @name app.directive:exampleDir
 * @param {<< what to write here? >>} parentContextExpression
 * @param {<< what to write here? >>} oneWayParameter
 * @param {Object=} twoWayParameter
 * @usage
 * <example-dir
 *   parent-context-expression="externalFn()"
 *   one-way-parameter="parentScopeVariable"
 *   two-way-parameter="parentScopeObject"
 * ></example-dir>
 **/
function exampleDir() {
  return {
    template: '...',
    scope: {
      parentContextExpression: '&',
      oneWayParameter: '@',
      twoWayParameter: '="
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Inputs should be using `<` and `@` bindings. Outputs are realized with `&` bindings. Avoid `=` binding. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://blog.domenic.me/youre-missing-the-point-of-promises/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [Angular Material](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/41c9d00dbb3cd85a31c3a02693854f25b2f7a8df/src/components/fabSpeedDial/fabSpeedDial.js#L94) code you will see the source of this answer.

Here's a simplified version that looks more like the source in the question.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc directive
 * @name exampleDir
 *
 * @param {string} one-way-parameter A One way.
 * @param {expression=} parent-context-expression An Expression
 */
function ExampleDir() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',

    scope: {
      oneWayParameter: '@?oneWayParameter',
      parentContextExpression: '=?parentContextExpression'
    },
}
```

According to my experience with the Closure Compiler (which is not the same as JSDoc, nor is it ngDoc):

The type of `scope` is `{Object<string>}`.

The values of `scope` params don't exist until `$onInit` is run on the controller's `class`, so they must be nullable in the constructor. You could provide those types like this;

```
class SomeCtrl {
  constructor() {
    /** @type {?boolean} */
    this.oneWayParameter;
  }

  $onInit() {
    this.oneWayParameter = 'this is not a boolean';
  }
}
```

In this example `this.oneWayParameter = 'this is not a boolean';` throws an error in Closure because the property expects a boolean, but finds a string.